# Chrome extension xmlhttprequest() not working : succeeds to read, but fails to send information to an external server

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm writing a chrome extension that is connected to an external php server. There are two main things that my chrome app does regarding the interaction with ther server :
1. read the stored comments from the server and show it on the extension 
2. if a user writes a new comment, send it to the server so it can store the comment in the MySQL DB.

The problem I have is that while my extension has no problem fetching information from the server, it constantly fails to send new comments to the server. Since the reading function works, I assume that I have no problem with the CORS or anything.

This is the code I wrote to read the info from the server.

```
        function getUrl() {
    chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(w) {
      chrome.tabs.getSelected(w.id,
      function (response){
          link = response.url;
          //console.log(link);
          hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          var info="link="+link;
          //console.log(info);
          hr.open("POST", "http://nardis.dothome.co.kr/nardis_core/comment_load.php", true);
          hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
          hr.onload = () => {
            const data = hr.responseText;
            //console.log(data);
            box.innerHTML += data;
            //console.log(data);
          };
          hr.send(info);
      });
    });
    }
```

This is the code I wrote to send the information to the server.

```
function sendPost(){
  chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(w) {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(w.id,
    function (response){
        //const title = document.getElementById('title').value;
        const description = document.getElementById('comment').value;
        link = response.url;
        //console.log(link);
        hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        chrome.storage.sync.get(['u_id'], function(result) {
                  var info="description="+description+"&link="+link+"&u_id="+result.u_id;
                  hr.open("POST", "https://nardis.dothome.co.kr/nardis_core/mention_create.php", true);
                  hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                  hr.send(info);
                  location.reload();
        });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Why instead of handling `onload` you are doing `location.reload()` ?

Comment: @ariel im just trying to refresh my extension popup cuz when it refreshes it reads the comments from the web server

Comment: You should do it only after the response, maybe that's why you arent receiving. `hr.onload = () => { ...  location.reload(); };`